# SelectedItems ListView binding fails in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `ListView` like this

```xml
<ListView x:Name="lview" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedItems="{x:Bind SelectedItems}">

</ListView>
```

with this code-behind:

```cs
public IList<object> SelectedItems
{
    get => (IList<object>)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList<object>), typeof(MainPage),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    List<int> io = new List<int> { 111111, 222, 33333, 4444444 };
    lview.ItemsSource = io;
}
```

Here I am trying to bind a dependency property (`SelectedItems`) to my listview. But this gives me an error

> Error XDG0013 The property "SelectedItems" does not have an accessible
>   setter.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it not possible to bind `SelectedItems` to a dependency property?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757516/uwp-listview-bind-selecteditem-to-property-in-viewmodel see that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectedItems` property of a `ListView` is read-only as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selecteditems?view=winrt-18362#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListViewBase_SelectedItems), hence prohibiting two way binding in UWP.

However, you could bind each item [IsSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selectoritem.isselected?view=winrt-18362#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_SelectorItem_IsSelected) property to the viewmodel and get the collection of selected items by filtering only items with `IsSelected` to `true`.